# How to get the raw content of an outlook email message with Office JS API?

Tags: outlook, outlook-addin, office-js

I'm trying to check if the sender used a proxy email address. Comparing the from and sender properties isn't enough, so I thought of checking the raw message source itself.

**How do you get the raw message source with Office JS API?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just looking for a prebuilt solution to see and analyze message headers in Outlook and OWA, you can use [Message Header Analyzer](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/MHA). If you're building your own add-in, you can borrow source from there.

Basically, you have two options:

1. EWS
2. Rest

In both cases, what you want to retrieve is [PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADER](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/client-developer/outlook/mapi/pidtagtransportmessageheaders-canonical-property), aka 0x007D. The EWS request will look something like [this](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/MHA/blob/master/Scripts/GetHeadersEWS.js#L113):

```
function getHeadersRequest(id) {
    // Return a GetItem EWS operation request for the headers of the specified item.
    return "<GetItem xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages'>" +
        "  <ItemShape>" +
        "    <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>" +
        "    <t:BodyType>Text</t:BodyType>" +
        "    <t:AdditionalProperties>" +
        // PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS
        "      <t:ExtendedFieldURI PropertyTag='0x007D' PropertyType='String' />" +
        "    </t:AdditionalProperties>" +
        "  </ItemShape>" +
        "  <ItemIds><t:ItemId Id='" + id + "'/></ItemIds>" +
        "</GetItem>";
}
```

And you'll submit it through a call to [makeEwsRequestAsync](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp161019.aspx)

```
    var mailbox = Office.context.mailbox;
    var request = getHeadersRequest(mailbox.item.itemId);
    var envelope = getSoapEnvelope(request);
    mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync(envelope, function (asyncResult) {
        callbackEws(asyncResult, headersLoadedCallback);
    });
```

To do the same from rest, you first need to get the [rest ID](https://github.com/stephenegriffin/MHA/blob/master/Scripts/GetHeadersRest.js#L47) for the item:

```
function getItemRestId() {
if (Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.hostName === "OutlookIOS") {
    // itemId is already REST-formatted
    return Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId;
} else {
    // Convert to an item ID for API v2.0
    return Office.context.mailbox.convertToRestId(
        Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId,
        Office.MailboxEnums.RestVersion.v2_0
    );
}
```

And then send the request through AJAX:

```
var getMessageUrl = getRestUrl(accessToken) +
    "/api/v2.0/me/messages/" +
    itemId +
    // PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS
    "?$select=SingleValueExtendedProperties&$expand=SingleValueExtendedProperties($filter=PropertyId eq 'String 0x007D')";

$.ajax({
    url: getMessageUrl,
    dataType: "json",
    headers: {
        "Authorization": "Bearer " + accessToken,
        "Accept": "application/json; odata.metadata=none"
    }
}).done(function (item) {
```

The MHA source gives more context.

Comment: This way you can receive only raw headers and not the whole raw email like with the GraphAPI: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages/<resource_id>/$value